# Wrong when I use tensorflow and keras together?

Tags: tensorflow, keras

## This is the code where I mix tensorflow with keras.

```
def dense_block(x, nb_layers, nb_filter, growth_rate, bottleneck=False, dropout_rate=None, weight_decay=1e-4,
                  grow_nb_filters=True, return_concat_list=False):
    ''' Build a dense_block where the output of each conv_block is fed to subsequent ones
    Args:
        x: keras tensor
        nb_layers: the number of layers of conv_block to append to the model.
        nb_filter: number of filters
        growth_rate: growth rate
        bottleneck: bottleneck block
        dropout_rate: dropout rate
        weight_decay: weight decay factor
        grow_nb_filters: flag to decide to allow number of filters to grow
        return_concat_list: return the list of feature maps along with the actual output
    Returns: keras tensor with nb_layers of conv_block appended
    '''
    concat_axis = 1 if K.image_data_format() == 'channels_first' else -1
    x_list = [x]
    for i in range(nb_layers):
        cb = __conv_block(x, growth_rate, bottleneck, dropout_rate, weight_decay)
        ########################################################
        #This is where I mix tensorflow with keras.
        cb = K.reshape(cb,(-1,7*7*32))
        W = weight_variable([7*7*32,7*7*32])
        cb = tf.matmul(cb, W)
        cb = K.reshape(cb,(-1,7,7,32))
        x_list.append(cb)
        ######################################################
        x = concatenate([x, cb], axis=concat_axis)

        if grow_nb_filters:
            nb_filter += growth_rate
    if return_concat_list:
        return x, nb_filter, x_list
    else:
        return x, nb_filter
```

## but get the error like this:

AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute '_keras_history'

Comment: Are you using Keras from the TensorFlow build? Or is it the standalone Keras?

Comment: Thank you very much for the idea. I've solved the problem for two main reasons. First of all, I should only use the back end of keras instead of the back end of tensorflow. Secondly, the Lambda function of keras should be used to build the model.My solutions are as follows:

Comment: ```def multiply_weight(x):
    x = K.reshape(x,(-1,7*7*32))
    w = K.random_normal_variable(shape=(7*7*32,7*7*32), mean=0, scale=1) 
    x = K.dot(x, w)
    x = K.reshape(x,(-1,7,7,32))
    return x```

Answer (score 0):

you cannot usually mix separate keras install with tensorflow use the one provided within tensoflow,

try replacing keras as follows 
`from tensorflow import keras as K`

https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras

Comment: You can actually install Keras directly, which gets installed with either Tensorflow or Theano backend. The concept of Keras as part of Tensorflow is new.